# C++ (and ROS) - Include vs. forward declare of reference with set default and typedef

Tags: c++, include, default-value, ros, forward-declaration

I have two very related questions regarding forward declarations, their advantages and difference with `#include`s. After reading on them it's still unclear to me if:

- using a ConstPtr from a ROS message (like [this](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/librealsense2/html/Float64MultiArray_8h_source.html)) counts as a pointer and can be (somehow) forward declared, or requires an `#include`;
- `void foo(const Eigen::Vector3d& scale={0.001, 0.001, 0.001});` in a .h file would be fine with something like (but this doesn't actually compile)

  ```
  namespace Eigen
  {

  class Vector3d;
  }
  ```

at the top of the .h after all the other `#include`s or if I should use the proper header.

To be clear, the second issue is with the fact `scale` has a default value, which is actually the one I will always be using in the .cpp. This is the only instance where I'm using a Vector3d.

I'm also fairly certain if the forward declaration is enough I therefore would not need to include the proper header in the .cpp as well, since I'm only ever using the default value inside the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forward declaration of `X` is sufficient to use an `X*` or `X&` as a function parameter or class member, because the full definition of a class is not needed to be able to use its address.

But in order to create an object of that class, even one with a default value, you're going to need its definition.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So is it that ConstPtr is not a pointer per se, and that's why I need to include that header as well?

Comment: I think you will need to include the header in your CPP file if you want to call a function like `foo` that has a default parameter, because to pass the default value you need to know how to construct the object. But I did not parse the file you linked, so I'm not sure exactly what your use case is.

Comment: No, ok, I got the part regarding `foo` when you said in the answer I need to create an object, which means I need the constructor and thus the include.

The second bit was about the first question, which refers to ConstPtr. In the link, you would find:

    `typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::std_msgs::Float64MultiArray_<ContainerAllocator> const> ConstPtr;`

which I'm almost sure doesn't really count as a pointer since the syntax isn't something like `type * ConstPtr`.

Comment: Found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588075/forward-declarations-and-shared-ptr) which explains I should be able to do it, however my real msg would have me include std::allocator, which I'm not really using, so I'll include the message itself since it is what I really use. Leaving the link for anybody else interested.